# Original Parallax Backgrounds for iOS7

Tags: ios

It appears that Apple left out of the final version the original parallax backgrounds that were on the original beta. Does anyone know where to locate those old files?

NOTE: I've been able to find some low-res wallpapers in backups (the file is named LockBackgroundThumbnail.jpg), but the actual wallpaper doesn't seem to exist elsewhere.

The example background I used on the beta version is this one:

[image]

I'd like to obtain all of the original backgrounds that seem to have been removed from the final release.

Comment: Dave - Wouldn't the obvious answer to this be to participate in the developer program and extract the assets you want? I'm not sure we want to be the place for people to ask for others to post parts of Apple software whether it's NDA or beta or shipping. Asking how to inject a custom image into an OS or how to extract things seems a good use - but just where to download seems less good.

Comment: Perhaps. I'm a developer already, so I suppose I could dig into the .ipsw and find them that way. It didn't really occur to me to do so. I don't see why finding a download of them would be a problem. If I'm asking for an API, or a cracked .dmg, sure. But this is backgrounds, for goodness sake. It never occurred to me that this was an issue.

Comment: I just wanted to explain some of the flags we've gotten in a constructive manner. I don't have a personal problem and it's not something I see as needing to be taken down. We can discuss the merits or lack thereof of this on [meta] if needed.

Comment: Don't beta IPSWs go away from public access when the release is available?

Comment: Jason, yes, they do. I deleted mine (regretfully) but I can probably recover them if I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no appropriate manner in which to get these files AFAIK. But this is how it's done anyway.

- You need a copy of the beta IPSW

**MUST BE FIRMWARE FOR FIRMWARE WITH BOOTROM EXPLOIT**

- ARM11; iPhone 2G, iPod touch 1g, iPhone 3G
- ARMv6; iPod touch 2g
- ARMv7; iPhone 3GS, iPod touch 3g
- A4; iPad 1g, iPhone 4, iPod touch 4g, Apple TV 2G

Now follow these steps:

1. Convert it from *filename*.IPSW to *filename*.ZIP by renaming it. In OS X you can just highlight the file, press [Enter] and rename the file extension on Windows, you can just rename it from CMD Prompt

   C:\>ren iPhone3,1_7.0_11A4372q_Restore.IPSW iPhone3,1_7.0_11A4372q_Restore.zip
2. Open the ZIP *(WinRAR, WinZIP, Extract, whatever)* and extract the DMG file that is really big, around 1GB or more
3. Move it to somewhere easy to refer to. For this example, I am going to use the root of the drive. You will then need to grab DMG. This can be downloaded [here for MacOS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuwo0kcfqovv1d/dmg) or [here for Windows.](https://intdev.googlecode.com/files/dmg.exe) Move this to the same location as the unpacked DMG.
4. Go to [TheiPhoneWiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Beta_Firmware) and find the beta firmware you unpacked, and click on the Build Number. This will bring you to a page showing at the top the Root FileSystem Key. Copy the RootFS Key for the corresponding IPSW. I will use BETA 1 as the example.

   [image]
5. Use the following syntax to decrypt the DMG:

   ./dmg extract [main-fs-dmg] rootfs.dmg -k [key]
6. This will decrypt the DMG for you. Once you have this, navigate to:
   /InnsbruckVailPrime11A4372q.N90DeveloperOS/Library/Wallpapers/iPhone

You will now be able to access all the wallpapers in the BETA versions of iOS7.

**NOTE:** To make your life easier, I have also included a ZIP link with the iOS7 wallpapers in both the long and short sizes already. Enjoy!

[Download iOS7 Beta Wallpapers](https://mega.co.nz/#!8cQVFJQS!eHOw_lET2tAepR45xCRupVLRPdt_AwjXPPDq4Zmt6KU)